# Swiffy's export conflicts with google's guidelines

Tags: html, flash, gzip, banner, google-swiffy

This is a google flash to html5 banner question.

When shoving in SWF files to google's Swiffy, it tells me my filesize is e.g. 40kb, but then when i download the gzip file and open it the html file becomes 160kb, and there looks like there's a runtime.js file which is 420kb. 
Google's guidlienes state that a)files need to be sent in a zip format not gzip b)they need to be under 150kb

So I tried the zippy flash expansion which worked great at 160kb which i could compress easily but then it still calls for https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.2.0/runtime.js
Google never let me embed scripts into flash banners, is this now allowed for html5 banners? Can I build banners this way and embed this runtime file from that gstatic site? Does anyone have any experience with this or who knows an alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're right, Swiffy output isn't feasible for standard banner ad networks, due to file size. Google does a lot of things; just because they built both Swiffy and AdWords doesn't mean those products go together. 
There's not an easy and usable way to convert a Flash banner to HTML5. We've had good results using GSAP tweens to build Flash and HTML versions of the same design. Or, if you can do all your animation with CSS transitions, that's probably going to be the smallest file size, but will still be over the 40k limit that many publishers still have. For those sites, you'll probably be stuck with either Flash, or a static image.

Comment: Yeah I always used gsap in flash with tweenlite/max and am now transitioning to html5. This question i posted a while go and I actually found this: DoubleClick does allow for larger banners, and it also alows for external script calling specifically from google swiffy servers. I say allows because I ran 60 banners for a bank last week and they got published easily. Well easily is a strong word... sucsessfully. Also google has rules for html5 banners letting them be 150kb zipped.. even though they unzip them on uploading which is really odd to me because it looks like it's over filesize.

Comment: There is no doco on this and i asked doubleclick with no response. It's just trial and error i guess. Feels like I'm back to flash MX times

Comment: Oh and I also found out that they convert any flash banner to html5 by default for mobile since this feb using swiffy if they're eligible. And i tried with many ads built with tweenlite/flash and they all tested as eligible. Just some other things I thought I'd share.