# Does Google Swiffy HTM5 ads compatible with Adwords

Tags: html, google-ads-api, google-swiffy

I have a simple flash banner want to convert it into HTML5 using Google Swiffy and want to make compatible with Google Adwords. Is it possible? If yes then how?

Thanks
Abdur Rahim

Comment: Provide what you have done so far.

Comment: Aparently not. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106342/swiffys-export-conflicts-with-googles-guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if your local convert (from Flash via Google Swiffy extension) don't output any conversion errors - just upload your original SWF at AdWords platform - Google converts in on the fly to the html5 (via server-side Swiffy).